# Horizontal title bar shadow while in full screen

Tags: 13.04, fullscreen, titlebar

While in full screen the horizontal shadow of the *title bar* (I am not too sure about its name) appears on top of everything. How can I get rid of it? It's quite distracting while coding in Guake mode and annoying while watching movies.

[image]

In the picture I've setup Guake with some transparency (that's why you can see things underneath), but the shadow is on the top of everything while I am in fullscreen. This, as I have already said, happens to me both while I am watching movies or programming in fullscreen mode.

This usually happens after awaking the laptop from hibernation. Now it looks like it has gone, but I am still wandering if someone knows something about it.

[image]

And here back it is >:[

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 3):

It's rather workaround then solution, but what You can do is to remove this shadow completely. To do so type commend below - it generally only renames the file, doesn't remove it.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/unity/6/panel-shadow.png /usr/share/unity/6/panel-shadow.png-removed
```

After that restart Unity by typing `unity` in alt+f2 console or in Terminal.

You can also bring back this shadow again anytime.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/unity/6/panel-shadow.png-removed /usr/share/unity/6/panel-shadow.png
```

And if You really need that shadow sometimes You can just create two hotkeys with commends above or with `&& unity` added to both of them.

And You can also check this out: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/fix-shadow-displayed-on-top-of-full.html .

Comment: Thanks @kcpr! I couldn't find anyone complaining about this problem when I wrote the question (May 10), but now (May 16) I do realise it is a general bug, and it is not my fault ^^. Still, I will not *accept* your question hoping for someone to give me a fix rather than a workaround ;)

Comment: Sure, I just hope it's useful for You in any way. ;)

Comment: Yes, indeed! Maybe I'm weird, but that shadow was definitely distracting me while programming! [Thumb up!] (When I'll get enough reputation points I will give you the actual *thumb up*.) Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

Download Unity Tweak Tool and on the main window select Panel under Unity to show the available options for the panel. Turn Transparency On and move the Transparency level handle all the way to the right.

[image]

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am not trying to get rid of the shadow. I was just trying to find out why it comes above everything when I enter in fullscreen mode.
Right now the problem has disappeared. Therefore I believe it's a bug of the current distribution.